# Something wrong with Android Manifest for a tablet

Tags: android, android-manifest, manifest, tablet

I wrote a small calculator app for android and then I tried it on a Huawei tablet and it worked fine.
But then I put this code in the manifest file

```
 <uses-sdk
  android:minSdkVersion="11"
  android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
<supports-screens
  android:anyDensity="true"
  android:largeScreens="true"
  android:normalScreens="true"
  android:resizeable="true"
  android:smallScreens="true"
  android:xlargeScreens="true"
  android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="600" />
```

and then the app shows only in 1/3 of the tablet. If I remove the code it works fine, so something must be wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Check this: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html
As you can see, all of your attributes are true by default, except one - it is xlargeScreens. According to documentation it differs by android versions, so you could broke smth by setting it to the true.
What was your purpose?